# Can I Iterate from JSON array in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli

I'm using Azure Pipelines to make some automations, and in one job I wish to iterate from a JSON to config WebApp settings. I'm using powershell, but I'm struggling to do something like this, made in Python:

```
import json

varJson = json.loads('''{
        "key1": "value1", 
        "key2": "value2", 
        "key3": "value3",
        "key4": "value4"
    }''')

for i in varJson:
    print(f'az webapp config appsettings set -g resourceGroup -n appName --settings {i}=\"{varJson[i]}\"')
```

The output I wish is something like:

```
az webapp config appsettings set -g resourceGroup -n appName --settings key1="value1"
...
```

I tried to use objects, but it's confuse to me:

```
$Json = @'
{
    "key1": "value1", 
    "key2": "value2", 
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4"
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json
ForEach-Object -InputObject $Json {
    Write-Host $_.PSObject.Properties.Name 
}
Write-Host $Json
```

Can I do something in PowerShell similar of what I did in python? Or there's an easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$fromJson = @'
{
    "key1": "value1", 
    "key2": "value2", 
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4"
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($prop in $fromJson.psobject.Properties) {
  @"
    az webapp config appsettings set -g resourceGroup -n appName --settings "$($prop.Name)=$($prop.Value)"
"@
}
```

Note:

- `.psobject` is an [*intrinsic member*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members) that PowerShell makes available on objects of any type, and it is a rich source of reflection; its `.Properties` property returns a collection of objects describing the properties of the object at hand, each of which have a `.Name` and `.Value` property.
- As in your Python code, the `az` command line is merely *printed as a string*, not invoked.

  - To perform the actual invocations, remove the `@"` and `"@` lines (the construct as a whole is a PowerShell [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings)).
- `"$($prop.Name)=$($prop.Value)"` results in something like `"key1=value1"`, which PowerShell would pass *without quoting* to `az`; only if the value part contained *spaces* would PowerShell double-quote the - entire - argument.

  - If `az` requires *partial* quoting on its command line, such as `key1="value 1"`, the easiest solution is to call via `cmd.exe /c`:

    ```
    cmd /c "az webapp config appsettings set -g resourceGroup -n appName --settings $($prop.Name)=`"$($prop.Value)`""
    ```
  - If you want to be shielded from such intricacies, consider installing the [`Native` module](https://github.com/mklement0/Native) (`Install-Module Native`), whose `ie` function automatically performs the partial quoting for you (if the value part contains spaces), among other features, so that you can focus on PowerShell's syntax alone:

    ```
    ie az webapp config appsettings set -g resourceGroup -n appName --settings "$($prop.Name)=$($prop.Value)"
    ```